# How to make a seperate list based on certain numbers from a previous list?

Tags: python

Hey guys trying to finish my program. Here is my code:

```
lists = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]

#I want to make a new list consisting of only numbers above 50 from that list
if any(list > 50 for list in list):
newlists = list
```

I don't know how to do it. I'm doing something wrong, can anyone help me?

Comment: Try giving my video on [list comprehensions](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw) a watch.

Comment: Also, as a side note, avoid using `list` as a variable name.  You'll shadow the builtin `list` and can end up with some pretty confusing bugs that way

Answer (score 3):

something like this will work:

```
new_list = [ x for x in lists if x > 50 ]
```

This is known as a "[list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)" and can be extremely handy.

Answer (score 3):

`newlist = [x for x in lists if x > 50]`

Read about list comprehensions [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Answer (score 2):

Two options. Using list comprehensions:

```
lst = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
[x for x in lst if x > 50]
```

And using `filter` in Python 2.x:

```
filter(lambda x: x > 50, lst)
```

Or using `filter` in Python 3.x, as pointed in the comments, `filter` returns an iterator in this version and if needed, the result needs to be converted to a list first:

```
list(filter(lambda x: x > 50, lst))
```

Anyway, the result is as expected:

```
=> [60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
```

Comment: except in python 3, `filter` doesn't return a `list` :-p.  I thought about adding filter to my answer, but I really believe that a list-comprehension is the way to go in this particular case.  `filter` should really only be used if you have a function already defined and ready to go (IMHO).